# Can't combine <character> and <double> on adding sort function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to sort the data based on the median price i.e m , but when I added sort function it throwing me an error that

Error: Can't combine `locationName` character and `m` double

how can I sort data based on newly mutated column in my case m which median price ?

```
df %>% 
    filter_at(.vars= vars(area), all_vars(grepl('10 Marla',.))) %>%
    group_by(locationName,area,city) %>%
     mutate(m = median(price)) %>%
     select(locationName,area,city,m) %>% 
     sort(m,decreasing = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sort` within `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter_at(.vars= vars(area), all_vars(grepl('10 Marla',.))) %>%
   group_by(locationName,area,city) %>%
   mutate(m = median(price)) %>%
   select(locationName,area,city,m) %>% 
   mutate(m = sort(m,decreasing = TRUE))
```

---

If the intention is to order the rows based on 'm', use `arrange`

```
df %>% 
 filter_at(.vars= vars(area), all_vars(grepl('10 Marla',.))) %>%
 group_by(locationName,area,city) %>%
 mutate(m = median(price)) %>%
 select(locationName,area,city,m) %>% 
 arrange(desc(m))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. why sort is working with mutate , but it wasn't without it  here?

Comment: @usman You may need to extract the column with `pull` or `.$` i.e. `%>% .$m %>% sort(., decreasing = TRUE)`